# why it happends if i write sql query in two different ways in eclipse

Tags: mysql

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_database","root","mysql");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    System.out.println("pass");
    String sql="DELETE FROM user"
            + "WHERE userId='sh123'";
    int rowAffected = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    System.out.println("row affected" + rowAffected);
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> look at this code, well, it is working fine. but 1 thing is IRRITATING me,
>   if i write the sql query in this form it works fine:-

```
String sql="DELETE FROM user WHERE userId='sh123'";
```

but, if i write the sql query in this form then it is not working:-

```
String sql="DELETE FROM user"
        + "WHERE userId='sh123'";
```

it gives error 
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'userId='sh123'' at line 1"

give me the reason, why it happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing spaces:

```
String sql="DELETE FROM user "
        + "WHERE userId='sh123'";
```

Your version was:

```
String sql="DELETE FROM userWHERE userId='sh123'";
```

That is not syntactically correct.

Comment: thank you sir,
actually i have not notice that it will affect the code....